# How to tell if a Logitech Google Meet device has joined a meeting?

Tags: google-meet

I would like to query to find out if our Logitech Google Meet devices have joined a meeting. There is no way to auto-join when a meeting is in progress, so I want an app that runs on a little raspberry pi that tells people to remember to join the meeting when the meeting starts.

There is no API that I can find on Google Meet to report if the conference room has joined or not. I've turned on admin logging and this is not obviously logged, at least not anywhere that I can find it. There is a beta API that I've applied to google to get access to.

Is there any way to query the logictech device itself? Is there something that might show up on the network trace (other than the large number of packets flowing) ?